# Trace and Lie derivative of a $(1,1)$-tensor commute (Direct proof)

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, trace, lie-derivative, contraction-operator

My question is same as [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2503445/272127) but I want to use direct properties of Lie derivative and trace to prove (I know another proof using this fact that pullback map commutes with contraction)

$$\operatorname{tr}(\mathscr{L}_X S) = \mathscr{L}_X \operatorname{tr}S.$$

To do this I have calculated the following:

$$\operatorname{tr}(\mathscr{L}_X S)=g\Big((\mathscr{L}_X S)e_i,e_i\Big)=g\Big(\mathscr{L}_X Se_i,e_i\Big)-g\Big(S\mathscr{L}_X e_i,e_i\Big)=\mathscr{L}_Xg\Big( Se_i,e_i\Big)-(\mathscr{L}_Xg)( Se_i,e_i)-g(Se_i,\mathscr{L}_Xe_i)-g\Big(S\mathscr{L}_X e_i,e_i\Big)=\mathscr{L}_X \operatorname{tr}S-(\mathscr{L}_Xg)( Se_i,e_i)-g(Se_i,\mathscr{L}_Xe_i)-g\Big(S\mathscr{L}_X e_i,e_i\Big) $$

But I couldn't cancel out the extra terms. Any tiny hint (suffices)?

Comment: How do you define the Lie derivative of a $(1,1)$ tensor?

Comment: As defined in the linked post.

Comment: i.e. $(L_XS)(Y)=L_XS(Y)-S([X,Y])$.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand\tr{\operatorname{tr}}$By the linearity of trace, it suffices to prove the identity for $S = \theta\otimes v$, where $\theta$ is a $1$-form and $v$ is a vector field. First, observe that
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_X(\theta\otimes v) &= (\mathcal{L}_X\theta)\otimes v + \theta\otimes (\mathcal{L}_Xv)\\
\tr (\theta\otimes v) &= \langle\theta, v\rangle.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\tr\mathcal{L}_X(\theta\otimes v) &= \tr((\mathcal{L}_X\theta)\otimes v + \theta\otimes (\mathcal{L}_Xv)\\
&=\tr((\mathcal{L}_X\theta)\otimes v) + \tr(\theta\otimes (\mathcal{L}_Xv))\\
&= \langle \mathcal{L}_X\theta, v\rangle + \langle \theta, \mathcal{L}_Xv\rangle\\
&= X\langle \theta,v\rangle\\
&= \mathcal{L}_X(\tr \theta\otimes v)
\end{align*}

Comment: Dear Deane: trace is linear but $L_X$ is not. Does this weaken your proof?

Comment: @C.F.G, I don't think so, but you should check it carefully. Note that the Lie derivative does satisfy $$\mathcal{L}_X(T_1+T_2) = \mathcal{L}_XT_1 + \mathcal{L}_XT_2$$ but $$\mathcal{L}_X(fT) = f\mathcal{L}_XT + (Xf)T.$$ I think this is enough to make it all work. The truth is that whenever I find an abstract proof like this, I usually check to make sure it all works using local coordinates. However, I didn't do so here.